# Calling startActivity from service doesn't allow to switch the screen off

Tags: android, android-activity, android-service

Hello Stackoverflow users,

I am trying to open new activity with the following code for this condition `if(intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON))` (the service has BroadcastReceiver)

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, OverlayActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```

The problem is when new activity is opening, the screen time out settings doesn't work as before and the screen is always on. There is no flag FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON in the activity. Activity just has empty onCreate() method. I can't figure out what is the problem. Why the screen doesn't switch off after screen time out (15 seconds)? When I run service without this activity it disables screen as usually.

Comment: Which android version you are checking for ?

Comment: Android version 4.3 (Galaxy S3 and Nexus 4)

Comment: unless you are doing something else like holding a power lock or having android:keepScreenOn="true" in the layout for the activity on one of the views, then it shouldn't do that

Comment: There is no any attribute like this android:keepScreenOn="true". Concerning to the WakeLock I even have commented all that part. But as soon as it opens activity after KeyGuard (KeyGuard disables user by touching screen) time out is gone. Without commenting release wake lock doesn't help as well.

Answer (score 0):

for Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF and Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON you CANNOT declare them in your Android Manifest!

Might be you are doing this mistake.

Check this code -

```
public class ScreenReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    public static boolean wasScreenOn = true;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF)) {
            // do whatever you need to do here
            wasScreenOn = false;
        } else if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON)) {
            // and do whatever you need to do here
            wasScreenOn = true;
        }
    }

}
```

and in Activity -

```
public class ExampleActivity extends Activity {

    private BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // initialize receiver
        final IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON);
        filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);
        mReceiver = new ScreenReceiver();
        registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);
        // your code
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        // when the screen is about to turn off
        if (ScreenReceiver.wasScreenOn) {
            // this is the case when onPause() is called by the system due to a screen state change
            Log.e("MYAPP", "SCREEN TURNED OFF");
        } else {
            // this is when onPause() is called when the screen state has not changed
        }
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        // only when screen turns on
        if (!ScreenReceiver.wasScreenOn) {
            // this is when onResume() is called due to a screen state change
            Log.e("MYAPP", "SCREEN TURNED ON");
        } else {
            // this is when onResume() is called when the screen state has not changed
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        if (mReceiver != null) {
            unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);
            mReceiver = null;
        }
        super.onDestroy();
    }

}
```

Probably this might solve your issue.

Cheers :)

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get what I can't declare?

Comment: These are the states and only allowed to catch them while your activity is running. Try to remove them from Manifest and see if this works for you.

Comment: Sorry probably I wrote something not clear. Th screen of and on events are caught in BroadcastReceiver

Comment: Your answer tells how to register service for that event. In my case it works. When service runs and after that I don't open new activity, screen time out works fine. But as soon as I startActivity from the service, it doesn't work anymore.